# Why is XMLHttpRequest.onerror invoked when the web request actually succeded?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am using the following little gem within the background script of a Mozilla webextension:

```
function makeRequest(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
            console.log("begin makeRequest");
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.onload = function() {
                    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                            console.log("resolve makeRequest");
                            resolve(xhr.response);
                    } else {
                            console.log("reject makeRequest");
                            reject({
                                    status: this.status,
                                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                            });
                    }
            }
            xhr.onerror = function() {
                    console.log("reject makeRequest by error");
                    reject({
                            status: this.status,
                            statusText: xhr.statusText
                    });
            }
            xhr.send(null);
            console.log("makeRequest sent");
    });
}
```

I invoke this with a line like  `makeRequest("http://www.example.com")` and I can verify from the Apache access log at www.example.com, that the request succeeds (status code "200"). In particular, this makes me confident that the request does not fail due to some misisng permissions in the manifest or the like. Consequently, I'd expect the `xhr.onload` to be invoked with `this.status == 200`.
But instead of this, the `xhr.onerror` is invoked, i.e., the console log reads

```
begin makeRequest
makeRequest sent
reject makeRequest by error
```

Why? (As in : How is this even possible?)

Comment: Is that the *complete* contents of console.log? What is `this.status`?

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to `xhr` within the onload handler.  Use `xhr.status`

Comment: @James OK, thanks for the hint. Though it shouldn't matter as `this.status` is not even evaluated before the system decides to invoke `onerror` instead of `onload`...

Comment: It's worth noting that if the response's content doesn't match the MIME type unusual errors can occur. (A common example is probably a MIME type of `*/json` where the content would cause `JSON.parse(content)` to throw an error)

Comment: @Quentin To be complete, there is a `TypeError: $(...).bootstrapValidator is not a function` with source `main.js` between sent and reject

Comment: What's the URL?  Are you performing a cross-server request that's being denied?  That would trigger onerror.

Comment: @PatrickBarr Good hint. The MIME type *is* `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`. However, if I copy/paste the output to an online parser such as http://json.parser.online.fr/ , it seems to be ok. At any rate, if I change the MIME type at the server to `text/plain` there should be no way the MIME type mismatches - but I still end up in `onerror`

Comment: @James Yes, the request is cross-server (as in: ultimately the request to www.example.com is made from the background script as a reaction to a message sent from a content script injected into a tab showing www.something-else.com. So do I have to add www.example.com to the permissions in the manifest somehow? But if the lack of this prevents the http response from going in, why isn't the request blocked from going out in the first place? If it's a security feature, I would have expected the data leak by the request to be blocked as well ...?!

Comment: Not 100% sure but I would check [content_security_policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_security_policy)

Comment: @James Fair enough. I changed the url to https, added `"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' https://*.example.com"` to the manifest.json, but nothing changes. Besides, as CSP is a security feature, I would again expect a failure to manifest in the *request* being blocked and not the *response*

Comment: [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629635/firefox-webextensions-and-cross-domain-privileges)